# How to make image extraction feature local binary patterns in xcode by using swift language

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Excuse me, I am doing my final paper, I should make an image extraction in ios app, I just can show the image in imageview, and I don't know how to make image extraction feature local binary patterns, if you could help me, I would thank to you and appreciate it. thank you for attention, hope fully you could help me

I have tried to show image and install the openCV

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var openCVVersionLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var myimageview: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        //Invoke functions in OpenCVWrapper class from swift
        //openCVVersionLabel.text = OpenCVWrapper.openCVVersionString()
    }

    @IBAction func chooseimage(_ sender: Any)
    {
        let image = UIImagePickerController()
        image.delegate = self

        image.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary

        image.allowsEditing = true

        self.present(image, animated: true)
        {
            //After it is complete
        }
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any])
    {
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage
        {
            myimageview.image = image
        }
        else
        {
            //Error message
        }
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

I need my image in imageview extract feature in method local binary patterns